# I need to get my logo on top right and need my other list elements in the nav bar

Tags: html, css

Basically I'm making a project for college and I need the logo on the left hand side which is not appearing at all right now, the `nav` buttons on the right and some social media icons on the rightmost, I haven't added the icons yet since i cant even get this part right.

I know the code is messed up but this is my first time with CSS and HTML and also if i want to insert a bullet between the `nav` items is that possible?

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ouFlz) is the CodePen

`head`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ab.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Slider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ab.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
        });
</script>


<body class="content">
  <header>
    <div class="navbuttons">
        <div class="nav-main-wrapper">
            <nav class="nav-main">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a class="logo" href="index.html"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">QUIET</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">RAIN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">THOUGHTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CRAZY</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

`css`

```
.navbuttons{
    background:#0099cc;
    position:relative;
    padding: 30px 0px 33px 0px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
header{
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:-1;
} 
.branding img{
position: relative;
top: 0px auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 156px 0px;
}
.logo{
    background: url("http://tinypic.com/r/30k62ae/5");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:140px;
    display:block;
    width:105px;
    margin-top:-80px;
    left: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-main-wrapper{
    float:left;
    min-width: 470px;
    bottom: 300px:
    margin: 22px 0px 22px 47px;
}
.nav-main{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
.nav-main ul{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    font-size:22px;
}
.nav-main ul li{
    display:inline;
    color:#237dac;
    font-family: LeagueGothic;
}
.nav-main ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 128px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-main ul li a:hover{
    color:#056495;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-main ul li:last-child:after{
    content: "";
}
.nav-main ul li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
}
@font-face {
font-family: LeagueGothic;
src: url('LeagueGothic-Regular.otf');
}
```

Comment: You should post your code here and not just links to demo fiddles..

Comment: But... Where's the logo on your HTML code? I only saw a `a` element without nothing.

Comment: @LeonardoManrique i've put it in the style sheet as a background url. :/ but it isnt showing up.

Comment: @Mr.Alien i'm sorry im relatively new and couldnt figure how to do that without making the question seem very untidy.

Comment: @CrazyRoach Done, hope you got how we expected :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien that was so kind of you! Thank you so much!

Comment: @CrazyRoach You welcome :) also don't forget to accept the answers if it solves your issue, this will help future visitors to refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following CSS below :

```
    body{
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbuttons{
        background:#0099cc;
        position:relative;
        padding: 30px 0px 33px 0px;
        height: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    header{
        margin-top: 0px;
        position: relative;
        z-index:-1;
    } 
    .branding img{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px auto;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px 0px 156px 0px;
    }
    .logo{
        background: url("http://tinypic.com/r/30k62ae/5");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:140px;
        display:block;
        width:105px;
        margin-top:-80px;
        left: 30px;
        margin-left: 30px;
        padding: 0;
        float:right;
    }

    .nav-main-wrapper{

        min-width: 470px;
        bottom: 300px:
        margin: 22px 0px 22px 47px;
    }
    .nav-main{
        float:left;
        clear:both;
        margin:-46px 0 0 ;
    }
    .nav-main ul{
        float:left;
        display:block;
        font-size:22px;
        margin:0px; padding:0px;
    }
    .nav-main ul li{
        display:inline;
        color:#237dac;
        font-family: LeagueGothic;
    }
    .nav-main ul li a{
        color: #fff;
        margin-left: 128px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .nav-main ul li a:hover{
        color:#056495;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .nav-main ul li:last-child:after{
        content: "";
    }
    .nav-main ul li a {
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @font-face {
    font-family: LeagueGothic;
    src: url('LeagueGothic-Regular.otf');
    }
```

HTML Source below :

```
<body class="content">
<div class="navbuttons">
  <div class="nav-main-wrapper">
    <div class=""> <a class="logo" href="#"> Your Logo</a></div>
    <nav class="nav-main">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li><a href="#">QUIET</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RAIN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">THOUGHTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CRAZY</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now my logo is on the blue div but it isn't being fully displayed, like only part of it is visible, could you help me out with that too? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

You link your logo to http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=30k62ae&s=5 which is not an image, but a page.

Link it to http://oi41.tinypic.com/30k62ae.jpg instead.

Comment: I am using the original jpg file in my code, uploaded it just to post here, it still shows up partially. :/

Comment: @CrazyRoach: I don't think you quite understand how this works. When giving code to people to look at, you give them a code as close as humanly possible to the code you have that's causing the problem. We should be able to see the problem *instantly* and without having to jump through hoops (would you help someone who doesn't make the effort to do this?). This code provides an accurate solution to the problem present in your code. If you had another problem, maybe you should have given us your **correct** code?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I'm sorry, this is actually my first time working with html and css, i know my approach must be silly. I'll try figure it out on my own. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @CrazyRoach: That's not the problem, I've downvoted 2 answers because their code didn't work when I tested it, and upvoted this one because it solves the problem. So now, my decision, based on this new information, was wrong, and I can't really change it unless they edit their answers. Please read [help] to understand how to ask better.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha No i get it, i'm sorry. I won't post any questions again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #333;
}
.menu ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #333;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
    background: #555;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 40px
}
.logo {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="logo" href="#"><img src="http://oi41.tinypic.com/30k62ae.jpg" width="119" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```